# what is blocking mode in java

Tags: java, nio

I am new to java nio,i am reading java nio tutorial ,can any one explain what is blocking mode.
In tutorial i read -- 'A FileChannel cannot be set into non-blocking mode. It always runs in blocking mode'

Comment: Whether IO reads/writes block the current process or happen asynchronously.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SelectableChannel.html#bm

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: Of course it is about programming, and it isn't a resource request either. Possibly 'too broad', and almost certainly a duplicate, but I think it can be answered here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Blocking mode means that the current thread cannot make forward progress until the I/O operation succeeds or fails. In non-blocking mode, if the operation cannot make forward progress immediately, control is returned to the thread so that it can try the operation again later.

Historically, "fast" I/O, such as accesses to disks, is offered only in blocking mode. "Slow" I/O, such as operations that wait for a response over a network, are offered in both modes.

Comment: Is it "try the operation again later" or "the operation happens _in the background_" and the thread can check back on its status or be actively notified of success via a callback?

Comment: @BoristheSpider They're really equivalent. If some operation happens in the background, then you will have to try the operation of getting the results of it later. If you can try the operation later and get different results, then some operation happens in the background that changes the results when you try later.

Comment: @Boris the Spider: *both*. When the operation implies “return the current contents of the buffer”, then successfully trying it again later implies that the buffer has been filled meanwhile in the background… In NIO, using a non-blocking `SelectableChannel` implies that you may use a `Selector` to monitor progress of the background transfers. In contrast, an `AsynchronousFileChannel` allows you to use call-backs, but that’s an asynchronous transfer different to that of a non-blocking channel.